# Use Ajax post select modal in PartialView of ASP.NET Core MVC is null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Ajax code

```
$(function(){    
    var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
            var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
            var sendData = new FormData(form.get(0));        
    $.ajax({
                url: actionUrl,
                method: 'post',
                data: sendData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (redata) {
                    ...
                },
                error: function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                }
            })
        })
}
```

In the partial view, I use select object `#EmpSelect` to add value and text to select object `#RolesList`, then use ajax post ID, Title, isVirtualGroup and RolesList to controller.

But the RolesList is always null, how can I do fix it?

[image: ajax request]

javascript code

```
$('#AddRolesGroup').click(function () { $('#EmpSelect :selected').map(function (row, item) { console.log(item.text); $('#RolesList').append("<option value='" + item.value + "'>" + item.text + "</option>") }); });
```

View about select object part

```
<div id="area">
    <select id="EmpSelect" class="form-select col-md-12" size="8"
                            multiple aria-label="EmpSelect">
    </select>

    <button class="btn" type="button" id="ClearSelect">Clear Select Roles</button>

    <select asp-for="RolesList" asp-items="Model.RolesList" class="form-select col-md-12" size="8"
     multiple aria-label="RolesList">
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `RolesList`,and how do you get the value of `#RolesList`?

Comment: How do you pass RoleList to controller with ajax?The code only shows how fill the RoleList.

Comment: In the Post , The code of the first paragraph.
is my ajax code.

Comment: Yes,but how do you get the data of RoleList ?

Comment: at controller new selectlistitem object set to List<SelectListItem> RolesList then pass to view

Comment: This is how to pass data from controller to view,but your question is you pass data from view to controller,but you cannot get the data correctly.

Comment: Sorry, only now I found out that my first paragraph of AJAX Code did not explain clearly. It has been revised.

Comment: Can you share your form in the view?

Comment: Add View about select object part at post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the select is in the form and make sure you have selected values.Here is a demo:

```
<form id="form1">
    <div id="area">
        <select id="EmpSelect" class="form-select col-md-12" size="8"
                multiple aria-label="EmpSelect">
        </select>

        <button class="btn" type="button" id="ClearSelect">Clear Select Roles</button>

        <select id="RolesList" name="RolesList" class="form-select col-md-12" size="8"
                multiple aria-label="RolesList">
            <option value="1">role1</option>
            <option value="2">role2</option>
            <option value="3">role3</option>

        </select>
    </div>
</form>
<button onclick="postdata()">postdata</button>
```

js:

```
function postdata() {
            var sendData = new FormData($("#form1").get(0));
            $.ajax({
                url: "PostData",
                method: 'post',
                data: sendData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (redata) {
                    //
                },
                error: function (message) {
                    alert(message);
                }
            })
        }
```

action:

```
public IActionResult PostData(string[] RolesList)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I think I know where my problem is.
Based on your presentation, it seems that you can only get the selected data.
And my goal is all the information.
But this let me know where to find information.
thanks